# How to check when image is loaded as a background image?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using this code so that after the page has been loaded on each `.item` its `data-image` should be placed as a background image. The problem is that `#loadingsvg` should get faded out only when (at least) first image has been loaded. How can I check that?

```
<div id="myCarousel">
    <div class="item" data-image="asdf.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item" data-image="asdf2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item" data-image="asdf23.jpg"></div>
</div>

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#myCarousel .item').each(function(){

        // Take data-image
        var $this = jQuery(this),
        src = $this.data('image');

        if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
            // Set as background image
            $this.css('background', 'url(' + src + ')');
        }

        jQuery('#loadingsvg').fadeOut();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the element containing the data-image, and make your jquery code run after that element has loaded with the function 'complete'.

For example:

```
if ($("#image").complete) { yourFunction(); }
```

Now in your code, you want to execute the code after a css change (an animation). You could use a promise with a callback - look [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

In your case:

```
if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
            // Set as background image
            $this.css('background', 'url(' + src + ')').promise().done(function(){
                  jQuery('#loadingsvg').fadeOut();;
});
```

Or, a less elegant solution: you can add a timeout before you fade out, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){jQuery('#loadingsvg').fadeOut();}, 1000);
```